# Load (strings and nils) as strings

Tags: python, pandas

I am loading a CSV file with:

```
converters = {
    ...
    col1: str,
    ...
}

prop = pd.read_csv(
    'input/properties_2016.csv',
    dtype=types,
    converters=converters,
)
```

The data for that column is like:

> ```
> 'acura',123
> 'ford',234
> 'dodge',345
> ,567
> ```

So the fourth item is interpreted as a N/A value.

I want that column to load as a string. I think string is better than object because I'm new and it is easy for me to say "if it's an object you didn't do it right so fix how you import that column."

---

But afterwards when I inspect the column:

```
prop.dtypes['col1']
```

The type is `object`.

I was expecting the NA value to convert to a string because:

```
str(None)
```

does return

> ```
> 'None'
> ```

---

So how do I make this import as a string?

Answer (score 4):

Pandas sets the dtype of a Series of strings to be `object` so that
the strings can be of variable width. So as far as I can see, you are doing everything right already.

If your data is similar to what is shown you could even remove the `dtype` parameters -- `pd.read_csv` will detect the right dtype automatically. Instead of using the `converters` parameter you could use `keep_default_na=False` ([thanks to Mitch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394224/load-strings-and-nils-as-strings/45394308?noredirect=1#comment77749366_45394308) for this suggestion):

```
prop = pd.read_csv('input/properties_2016.csv', header=None, keep_default_na=False)
```

yields

```
         0    1
0  'acura'  123
1   'ford'  234
2  'dodge'  345
3           567
```

PS: Avoid using `converters` if you can -- the converter function is applied to each value in the column separately, so if your CSV is large that amounts to a lot of function calls, which can slow down the parsing considerably.